# Difference between TopDocs and Hits in apache lucene ?

Tags: java, apache, lucene

I have used `apache lucene` in my project. But I was unable to understand difference between `TopDoca` and `Hits`?

Also I need to implement `spell corrector` in `apache lucene`?

I have tried using `fuzzyQuery` but it didn't work?

Is there any alternative to implement spell corrector in apache lucene?

Answer (score 0):

`TopDocs` is the class returned from a search call that contains the best hits for the query.  The `Hits` class worked similarly, but was removed quite a while ago, in version 3.0.  It also didn't require passing in a number of hits to return, but that should now be handled by passing in a `Collector`.

And yes, there is a better way of handling spellchecking:  [org.apache.lucene.search.spell.SpellChecker](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_8_1/suggest/org/apache/lucene/search/spell/SpellChecker.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot. And about FuzzyQuery(Term) ??? Can I use this FuzzyQuery() for finding nearabout search results???

Comment: Yes, you can use a fuzzy query to search for fuzzy matches, particularly  with edit distance (Damerau–Levenshtein) 2 or less.  But if you are really trying to correct spelling, you should probably be using the `SpellChecker` instead.

Comment: I will implement SpellChecker. Thanks a lot.